# if echo xxx -> echo xxx

Tags: php, string, if-statement, numbers

This is my Code;

`$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$temperatur = explode('T":', $output);
echo substr($temperatur[1], 0, 4);`

the echo substr gives me a number (e.g. 44). Is there a way in php to check if this number is under 50 and if yes, echo "blablaba".

I did something like this, but it wont work

```
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$temperatur = explode('T":', $output);

$check = substr($temperatur[1], 0, 4);

if ($check < "50") {
    echo "blabalabla";
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please do some simple research before posting.

Comment: Thats what i did, but i am a beginner, sometimes its hard to dobresearch on a problem, when you dont know what do search exactly. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast it as an integer. I think this should do it.

```
$check = (int)substr($temperatur[1], 0, 4);
if ($check < 50) {
    echo "blabalabla";
}
```